# How to distinguish the meaning of "repair" and " fix"

Tags: american-english

Are both the same? When do we use "fix" and when do we use "repair"

Comment: How do the dictionaries define the two words?

Comment: *Fix* is far broader than *repair*, even in its informal usage. http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american-cobuild-learners/fix http://www.wordreference.com/definition/fix

Answer (score 6):

The differences can be subtle. (We'll ignore the meanings of *fix* that have nothing to do with repair at all.)

At their closest pairing, the two words mean essentially the same thing, the difference being that *repair* is an "H" word (part of the "high", or more formal, vocabulary) while *fix* is an "L" word (part of the "low", or less formal, vocabulary). That's the difference that makes a business offer a "repair service" rather than a "fixing service" (or a "mending service", for that matter) even if the people working there would answer *What do you do here?* with *I fix stuff*.

At another level, though, the difference is greater. *Repairing* is pretty much limited to putting things back to the way they were or restoring them to usefulness. *Fixing* often goes beyond that to include modifications or improvements. One would never speak of repairing something that is brand-new and in perfect working order (it doesn't need to be repaired), but brand-new shiny things can be fixed in order, for instance, to become useful to someone who has a disability that renders the brand-new shiny thing essentially useless to them in practice even though it would meet their needs in theory. You can *fix* a system that is working as designed but not working as desired; *repairing* the same system would imply something like eliminating the work-arounds that people have developed to get around the failings of the system.

Comment: Also you can fix the leaking faucet with a spanner, but repair it by taking it apart and replacing the broken sealing

Comment: i appreciate that.

Comment: @mplungjan - Sadly, I have seen more than a few "craftsmen" who were, perhaps, not at the top of their game "repair" things in exactly that sort of way. It's about intent, not process.