# Use "do" instead of many other verbs

Tags: meaning, word-usage, verbs, do

Is it popular, how often, and in which cases does "do" take place of other verbs? Can it be used in written and in spoken English? Can we use "do" instead of any verb? Should we often provide context in such situations?

Examples:

> - Hey, John. Do the window. It's cold in here. (Close the window)
> - Johanna, would you please do the dishes? The sink is full already. (Wash the dishes)
> - Ron did the ground all morning. He's dug up the entire garden. (Dug the ground)
> - Susan should do the papers before the office calls. They are in such a mess. (Pile up the papers)
> - I did the door last night. She always had trouble opening it. (Fixed the door)
> - Somebody, please do the light. It's so dark in here. (Turn on the light)

Comment: Using 'do' instead of 'leave' would cause problems.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "Hey, Steve, do her alone!" (Leave her alone)? I guess it sounds very awkward (I love this word "awkward").

Comment: In your third example i think 'did the digging' or 'did the garden' would be more idiomatic than 'did the ground'.

Comment: @Spagirl I guess so, yet I wanted to emphasis the verb "dig" that's been replaced with "did".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth though i wouldn't say 'has done the garden all morning', rather something like 'spent all morning doing the garden'.

Comment: @Spagirl Agreed. There are many more idiomatic examples.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Why "has done the garden all morning" when is should be "has been doing the garden all morning"?

Comment: People make mistakes (eg your 'when is should be'), but I think that this ('has done the garden all morning') is colloquially acceptable in the States.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree. I often misspell words and make mistakes. I would like to know where you came up with the "colloquially acceptable in the States"?

Comment: You tell me why you can write 'Ron did the ground all morning.' but I need to use a continuous construction, and I'll do some digging. Though 'We danced all night' sounds totally acceptable even to my British ears.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You are right. My bad.

Comment: It should have been: "Ron was doing the ground all morning"

Comment: Certainly grammatical, but the 'rule' obviously isn't that binding ('I should have been dancing all night').

Comment: @EdwinAshworth With all respect, I prefer good grammar and academic English. Except for Spoken English - I love slang.

Comment: 'Good grammar' being the variant preferred by yourself? The BBC (of 'It's goodnight from Bill and I' fame)? Huddleston, Pullum et al (a book senior contributors here have voiced their non-total endorsement of)? Strunk and White? Aarts? McCawley? Senior contributors (professors emeritus) here? (If the last, which one?)

Answer (score 3):

The [British Council_Learn English article](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/delexical-verbs-have-take-make-and-give) on delexical verbs addresses these issues:

> **do**
>
> We use *do* *the* with –ing nouns to do with work, especially work in the
>   house:
>
> *It’s your turn to do the cooking.*
>
> *You do the washing up and I’ll do the drying.*
>
> and with other nouns to do with work:
>
> *I need to do a few jobs around the house.*
>
> *I can’t come out this evening. I have a lot of work to do.*
>
> ............
>
> We use *do* with noun [phrase]s when it is obvious [or reasonably obvious]  what the action is:
>
> *I’ll have to do my hair before we go out. = I’ll have to brush my hair.*
>
> *Have you done your teeth? = Have you cleaned your teeth?*
>
> [**but**] A question like
>
> *Have you done the car?*
>
> could mean
>
> *Have you washed the car?*
>
> *Have you mended the car?*
>
> *Have you put petrol in the car?*
>
> depending on the context.

Comment: "We use do with nouns when it is obvious what the action is" Without context who could know that "Have you done your teeth?" means "Have you cleaned your teeth?" it could be, "Have you fixed your teeth?", "Have you brushed you teeth?", "Have you shined your teeth?"

Comment: Agreed; I'd expect '... do your hair' to include washing. I've adjusted their over-generalisation.

Comment: @SovereignSun wouldn't brushed and shined mean the same as cleaned in this context? And usually you get someone else to fix your teeth so that would be 'have you had/did you get your teeth *done*?

Comment: @Spagirl Some teeth are detachable, and need soaking.

Comment: @Spagirl As much as I've heard it. "To brush your teeth" means "To clean them with a toothbrush". "To shine your teeth" means "To brush them and make them whiter (shiny)", "To clear your teeth" is just an oral hygiene and can be done in many ways even by means of a dentist.

Comment: @Spagirl You can fix your teeth if you have detachable teeth. What you spoke of is closer to "repairing teeth".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You could send them your corrections concerning [or reasonably obvious].

Comment: @SovereignSun I've never encountered the phenomenon of people shining their teeth separately from any polishing that occurs during brush/cleaning. To me 'polishing your teeth' is something you get done by a dental hygienist. Shine and whiteness are not really synonymous. Re 'fixing', I think that's a BrEng/AmEng difference, i did mean repair. If you meant 'fix into your mouth' i'd call that 'putting in'.

Comment: @Spagirl That's obviously another question one should ask. I know different. You can brush your teeth and not shine them (polish or whiten, whatever). You can polish your teeth, whiten or shine them after you have brushed them by asking or not asking a dentist. "Fix" and "Repair" (http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/181969/how-to-distinguish-the-meaning-of-repair-and-fix) are different words. There is also "mend". (http://wikidiff.com/fix/repair) and (http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/mend-fix-repair.182419/). I don't see how Br.E. and Am.E. have anything to do with the difference.